# Why is my attempt to write to a file thwarted?

Tags: c#, file-io

This code:

```
string ticklerFile = "awardUpdateDates.txt";
StringBuilder replacementFile = new StringBuilder();
List<string> lions = File.ReadAllLines(ticklerFile).ToList();
foreach (string lion in lions)
{
    if (lion.Contains("Pulitzer"))
    {
        string newLine = string.Format("Pulitzer~{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("d"));
        replacementFile.Append(newLine + Environment.NewLine); 
        continue;
    }
    replacementFile.Append(lion + Environment.NewLine);
}
File.WriteAllText(ticklerFile, replacementFile.ToString());
```

...fails on the last line with,

```
"*System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024864
  Message=The process cannot access the file 'C:\AwardWinnersOnlyOriginal12UpdateUtil\AWO12OriginalUpdateUtil\bin\Debug\awardUpdateDates.txt' because it is being used by another process.*"
```

The file is not open elsewhere, that I can see. It is being opened when `File.ReadAllLines()` is called, but there is no `File.Close()` available, so I don't know if that's a problem or not, and if so, how to get around it.

### UPDATE

I thought maybe I could solve my problem with this code:

```
string ticklerFile = "awardUpdateDates.txt";
string newLine;
StringBuilder replacementFile = new StringBuilder();
List<string> lions = File.ReadAllLines(ticklerFile).ToList();
File.Delete(ticklerFile);
foreach (string lion in lions)
{
    if (lion.Contains("Pulitzer"))
    {
        newLine = string.Format("Pulitzer~{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("d"));

    }
    else
    {
        newLine = lion;
    }
    replacementFile.Append(newLine);
}
File.WriteAllText(ticklerFile, replacementFile.ToString());
```

...but I get the same error, on the File.Delete() line.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't search here for the specific error you received? If you search for "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" here, one of the many answers should provide a solution. I'll [get you started](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+process+cannot+access+the+file+because+it+is+being+used+by+another+process)

Comment: Have you ever used sysinternals procmon?  You might set breakpoints and use the handle search to confirm your suspicions.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Those links seem to deal with java-specific problems.

Comment: There are dozens of them that deal with C#. Sorry; I didn't realize I had to do all the work for a simple search. `[c#]` before the error message should do it for you.

Comment: Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx), `File.ReadAllLines` closes the file when it's done reading.

Comment: Could not reproduce.  I was able to run this same code without issue.  Maybe you have a build step that is holding onto a lock on the file?  Are you able to reproduce the problem in a simple test app outside of the context of your main app?

Comment: @TylerOhlsen: This is a very simple app; it's just a utility to support my web site.

Comment: @Tim: So if ReadAllLines closes the file, I would expect WriteAllText to open it, too; didn't see anything about that at the link, though. Besides, TylerOhlsen says it's working for him, so maybe it was just an anomaly...I just tried it again, and get the same err msg. I did not open the file from Explorer or anything prior to that code running, so...???

Comment: An aside: You can replace `Append(s + newline)` with `AppendLine(s)`.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: Thanks, Jim, I'll change that.

Comment: My bad - I was opening the file in the main form,and then not explicitly closing it. Changing it to this:

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("awardUpdateDates.txt"))

from this:

StreamReader file = new StreamReader("awardUpdateDates.txt");

...in the main form solves the problem.